# How to set up crosstab queries to count days for negative stock counts?

Tags: ms-access

Hello Stack overflow (and anyone googling similar questions in the future)!

I have a dataset that regularly reports which products are absent on a warehouse stockcheck, which I am trying to use to analyse when stock is or isn’t available. I’m essentially trying to identify “Has a part been reported as missing? -> If so, count the number of days it is missing until another part in the same category is reported as missing, but the original part was not reported as missing on that date (as we can assume it’s back in stock)”.

I’ve managed to make this work in excel, but my spreadsheet began to die from the calculation of 5 locations worth of categories and parts, let alone across the 600+ I’m working on! As a result, I’m trying to set up a similar function in Access to analyse which, and for how long, parts were out of stock.

My dataset looks something like:

| Location number | Location | Category | Date reported | Part Number | Part Description | Order number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | Car | 03/06/2021 | 2021 | Wheel A | 1 |
| 2 | London | Bus | 03/06/2021 | 1491 | Seat C | 2 |
| 3 | Manchester | Car | 01/06/2021 | 2021 | Wheel A | 3 |

My assumptions are that:-

•   My data is fed by individual workers who each cover a location, and check all stock for a random selection of categories each visit (with the idea that they cover all of their location’s categories within a certain number of visits) and record which parts are missing. There is no particular visit plan – it can be a random number of days between each visit. This data gets fed into a central table, which I have access to.

•   As my workers may not check all categories in a location on each visit, I must assume that a previously reported missing part is OOS until they check products in the same category, but do not report that part again.

I made this work on excel by setting up another column that concatenated my location, part number, and date reported, and then set up three tables (all of which are essentially locations, categories, and parts down my X axis, and dates across the Y axis):-

•   Table1, to look if my concatenated code was reported for each day (and if so, output 1 – essentially working in days) – essentially, was each part reported as missing for each category and location?

•   Table2, to look if any parts were reported for each category, for each location – essentially, how many parts were reported for each category for each location, and a value greater than 0 means we can assume that that category at that location has been checked by my workers for that date.

•   Table3, that for each location+category+day asked as a formula – IF(category was checked as per table2 = yes , pull the value of 1 for that part/location/category in table 1 , re-use yesterday’s value for this part/location/day in this table). For the 1st day in my date range, I used the values for table1 for that day as a “starting up” point.

When I look at table 3, I can visually the run of days products were out of stock, and can from there crunch numbers related to that, which is what I want!

My initial Access plan was to set up three crosstab queries, to mirror my three excel tables. I can make Table1 and Table2 very easily, but for the life of me can’t make table3 work (currently have a calculated expression that mirrors the formula I had in table 3, but something has gone amiss…).

**I’m looking for a steer/advice on setting up the expression in my crosstab query, or other ideas/approaches I could use to calculate how long each part is missing for**. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I’ve lost my mind going in circles today!

Edit:-

Simplified dataset I'm working with:-

| **Location** | **Category** | **Date Reported** | **Part number** | **Part Description** | **Order number** | **Concatenate code** | **Concatenate Code 2** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | Car | 03/06/2021 | 2021 | Wheel | 1 | 1443502021 |
| 1 | London | Bus | 03/06/2021 | 1491 | Seat | 2 | 1443501491 |
| 2 | Manchester | Car | 05/06/2021 | 2021 | Wheel | 3 | 2443522021 |
| 1 | London | Car | 05/06/2021 | 2021 | Wheel | 4 | 1443522021 |
| 1 | London | Car | 07/06/2021 | 2021 | Wheel | 5 | 1443542021 |
| 1 | London | Bus | 05/06/2021 | 1860 | Seatbelt | 6 | 1443521860 |
| 1 | London | Bus | 05/06/2021 | 1860 | Seatbelt | 7 | 1443521860 |
| 2 | manchester | Bus | 01/06/2021 | 1860 | Seatbelt | 8 | 2443481860 |
| 2 | Manchester | Bus | 06/06/2021 | 1860 | Seatbelt | 9 | 2443531860 |
| 2 | manchester | Bus | 04/06/2021 | 1491 | Seat | 10 | 2443511491 |
| 2 | Manchester | Bus | 06/06/2021 | 1491 | Seat | 11 | 2443531491 |

I'm trying to output something like (which I've made work in Excel):-

| **Location** | **Category** | **Part code** | **01/06/2021** | **02/06/2021** | **03/06/2021** | **04/06/2021** | **05/06/2021** | **06/06/2021** | **07/06/2021** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | Car | 2021 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | London | Car | 2626 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | London | Bus | 1491 |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 1 | London | Bus | 1860 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Manchester | Car | 2021 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Manchester | Car | 2626 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Manchester | Bus | 1491 |  |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Manchester | Bus | 1860 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| 3 | Liverpool | Car | 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Liverpool | Car | 2626 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Liverpool | Bus | 1491 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Or to return the value for how many concurrent days out of stock a part has been, like per day of this version:-

| **Location** | **Category** | **Part code** | **01/06/2021** | **02/06/2021** | **03/06/2021** | **04/06/2021** | **05/06/2021** | **06/06/2021** | **07/06/2021** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London | Car | 2021 |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | London | Car | 2626 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | London | Bus | 1491 |  |  | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 1 | London | Bus | 1860 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Manchester | Car | 2021 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Manchester | Car | 2626 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Manchester | Bus | 1491 |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | Manchester | Bus | 1860 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |  | 1 |
| 3 | Liverpool | Car | 2021 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Liverpool | Car | 2626 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Liverpool | Bus | 1491 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

My Access sql (that I then turned into a crosstab) to identify ordered parts per day:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T_stores.[Store Nos], T_stores.[Store Name], t_Stands.Brand, t_Productlookup.TPND, t_Productlookup.TITLE, t_gapdata.Quantity, t_gapdata.[Requested Date]
FROM ((T_stores 
INNER JOIN t_Stands ON T_stores.[Store Nos] = t_Stands.[Store Nos]) 
INNER JOIN t_gapdata ON (t_Stands.[Brand] = t_gapdata.[Brand]) AND (t_Stands.[Store Nos] = t_gapdata.[Store No])) 
INNER JOIN t_Productlookup ON t_gapdata.[Part Number] = t_Productlookup.[EAN];
```

And likewise, to identfy is parts were ordered for a location's category:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT T_stores.[Store Nos], T_stores.[Store Name], t_Stands.Brand, t_Productlookup.TPND, t_Productlookup.TITLE, t_gapdata.Quantity, t_gapdata.[Requested Date]
FROM ((T_stores 
INNER JOIN t_Stands ON T_stores.[Store Nos] = t_Stands.[Store Nos]) 
INNER JOIN t_gapdata ON (t_Stands.[Brand] = t_gapdata.[Brand]) AND (t_Stands.[Store Nos] = t_gapdata.[Store No])) 
INNER JOIN t_Productlookup ON t_gapdata.[Part Number] = t_Productlookup.[EAN];
```

These first two work fine, but I'm struggling to put them together with some sort of Iif calculated field for a third query:-

```
SELECT First(q_gaps_per_product.[Store Nos]) AS [FirstOfStore Nos], First(q_gaps_per_product.[Store Name]) AS [FirstOfStore Name], First(q_gaps_per_product.Brand) AS FirstOfBrand, First(q_gaps_per_brand_store.[Order Id]) AS [FirstOfOrder Id], First(q_gaps_per_product.TPND) AS FirstOfTPND, First(q_gaps_per_product.TITLE) AS FirstOfTITLE, First(q_gaps_per_product.[Requested Date]) AS [FirstOfRequested Date], First(IIf([q_gaps_per_brand_store]![Requested Date]>=[q_gaps_per_product]![Requested Date],[Quantity],"PREVIOUS DAY")) AS Expr1, [q_gaps_per_product]![Store Nos] & [q_gaps_per_product]![Quantity] & [q_gaps_per_product]![TPND] AS Expr2
FROM q_gaps_per_product LEFT JOIN q_gaps_per_brand_store ON q_gaps_per_product.[Brand] = q_gaps_per_brand_store.[Brand]
GROUP BY [q_gaps_per_product]![Store Nos] & [q_gaps_per_product]![Quantity] & [q_gaps_per_product]![TPND];
```

Expr1 is supposed to be how many days a product is out of stock, with the idea that "PREVIOUS DAY" would return the same criteria for the previous day, to show either running gaps or that a product was in fact available as a 0, but I haven't got that far yet.

Expr2 is basically something I tried to make up to group the results by, as I had an insane number of results due to my janky table relationships.

I sort of think this query is DOA, and I need to go back to the drawing board to reproduce something like my Excel tables / how many days out of stock products have been concurrently out of stock before.

Sorry for the sheer storm of words!

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as well as attempted code.

Comment: Thanks for the steer - I've thrown some more info up, and already feel bad about some of my queries...